# How to prevent MS Outlook to send winmail.dat attached in a plain text email?

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi, winmail.dat

I'm currently working with a web service which has to reply an email to the customers if some error happens or if the data sent is not in the correct format.
I'm using the class **MAPIMessage** to send mails maked as "unread" in any Microsoft Outlook account opened in the computer which runs the service.

This is the code of the method which sends the emails.

```
    private void EnviarMail(string destinatarios, string CC, string BCC, string asunto, string texto, byte[] buffer, string nombreArchivo)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destinatarios))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destinatarios", "El destinatario de correo no puede estar vacío");

        try
        {
            if (_mapi.OpenOutbox())
            {
                MAPIMessage message = new MAPIMessage();

                if (message.Create(_mapi, MAPIMessage.Priority.IMPORTANCE_NORMAL))
                {
                    message.SetSenderName(Settings.Default.Remitente);
                    message.SetSenderEmail(Settings.Default.RemitenteCorreo);
                    message.SetSubject(asunto);
                    message.SetBody(texto);

                    foreach(string destinatario in destinatarios.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        message.AddRecipient(destinatario.Trim());

                    //some other code irrelevant for the question 

                    if (buffer != null)
                    {
                       //doesn't matter right now
                    }

                    if (!message.Send())
                        throw new ApplicationException("No pudo enviarse el correo electrónico.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Like I said before, this mail has to be  only plain text, so I set the last two parameters as null in order to specify that the method doesn't have any attachment when I reply the message:

```
EnviarMail(someCustomerEmail, "", "", Properties.Resources.SomeSubject, someBodyText, null, "");
```

The fact is that this email includes the file winmail.dat and this is not what I want. This is how it looks by testing in a gmail account:
[image]